# Show that a function of a Cauchy-distributed r.v. Is also Cauchy-distributed.

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let X be Cauchy with parameters $\alpha$ and 1. Let $Y=\frac{a}{X}$ with $a\neq 0$. Show Y is also a Cauchy r.v. And find its parameters.

I'm supposed to get $\hat{\alpha}=\frac{a\alpha}{1+\alpha^{2}}$ and $\hat{\beta}=\frac{|a|}{1+\alpha^{2}}$.

When either $y\geq 0$ or $y<0$, I wind up with $f_{Y}(y)=\frac{a}{y^{2}}(\frac{1}{\pi} \frac{1}{1+(\frac{a}{y}-\alpha)^{2}})$. I'm having a lot of trouble with the algebra to extract $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$, though. I've tried working forwards and backwards. The way I started forwards is by multiplying out the $(\frac{a}{y}-\alpha)^{2}$, grouping together the $1+\alpha ^2$, and then pulling the $\frac{1}{y^{2}}$ in from the outside, and distributing it to all the terms. After this, things get a bit wonky.

Have any hints, tips, suggestions about how I should proceed. I've gone through several sheets of paper going down paths that didn't work, so I would immensely appreciate any help you could give me! Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  after expanding out the denominator, complete the square.

Comment: To get $((y - \frac{\alpha a}{1+\alpha^{2}})^2 +\frac{a^2}{(1+\alpha^{2})^{2}})(1+\alpha^{2})$ in the denominator?

Comment: GOT IT!! :) :) Thank you!